# Textures distortion in 3D

Tags: flash, 3d

I am using Papervision3D Flash 3D engine to render a model. Also I am noob in 3D =D

Model is simple, it's a parallelepiped with different textures on its sides.
All works just fine except one thing: whenever I change my visual angle to a model from 90° textures on the sides are distorted. I notices that it is common effect in 3D graphics, I saw that effect in games and other 3D renderers (i.e. away3D, three.js) even wth different 3D models.

Distorted texture on object (different view angle):
[image]

Normal texture on object (*same object and texture*) (view angle == 90°):
[image]

What is the reason of this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the engine is using affine texture mapping then compensating by using triangle subdivision. The distortion should become unnoticeable if you can either increase the number of triangles the engine divides surfaces into or make it use perspective correct texture mapping. [Some background here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_mapping).

You'll see a similar effect if you set the subdiv factor very high on [this](http://tulrich.com/geekstuff/canvas/perspective.html) demo.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, that's exactly what I need. Would google it deeper :)

Comment: yep, affine because of performance... @xaero: stop using pwd3 unless you have to, it's ago old by now... try Away3D or any other "modern" 3D engine if you care about your b... FP11 now has GPU acceleration

Comment: @xaero: If you found my answer useful/satisfactory you can accept it. (I wouldn't mention this normally except I notice you're new so you might've missed it.)